# U Boot : Bad CRC Error

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, u-boot, buildroot

I am getting CRC Error when i try to download uImage to the board,

```
Bytes transferred = 10543306 (a0e0ca hex)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 01000000 ...
Image Name:   bf609-0.0-3.10.10-ADI-2013R1
Image Type:   Blackfin Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
Data Size:    10543242 Bytes = 10.1 MiB
Load Address: 00001000
Entry Point:  002cf9ec
Verifying Checksum ... Bad Data CRC
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
bfin>
```

this is what i get using printenv command:

```
printenv
addip=set bootargs $(bootargs) ip=$(ipaddr):$(serverip):$(gatewayip):$(netmask):$(hostname):eth0:off
autoload=no
baudrate=57600
bootargs=root=/dev/mtdblock0 rw clkin_hz=(25000000) earlyprintk=serial,uart0,57600 console=ttyBF0,57600  ip=192.168.1.122:192.168.1.107:192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:"bf609-ezkit":eth0:off
bootcmd=run ramboot
bootdelay=5
ethact=mii0
ethaddr=02:80:ad:20:31:e8
fileaddr=1000000
filesize=a0e0ca
flashboot=bootm 0xB0100000
gatewayip=192.168.1.1
hostname="bf609-ezkit"
ipaddr=192.168.1.122
ipaddress=192.168.1.240
loadaddr=0x1000000
loads_echo=1
nc=set ncip ${serverip};set stdin nc;set stdout nc;set stderr nc
netmask=255.255.255.0
nfsargs=set bootargs root=/dev/nfs rw  nfsroot=$(serverip):$(rootpath),tcp,nfsvers=3
nfsboot=tftp $(loadaddr) $(nfsfile);run nfsargs;run addip;bootm
nfsfile=vmImage
ramargs=set bootargs root=/dev/mtdblock0 rw clkin_hz=(25000000) earlyprintk=serial,uart0,57600 console=ttyBF0,57600
ramboot=tftp $(loadaddr) $(ramfile);run ramargs;run addip;bootm
ramfile=uImage
rootpath=/romfs
serveraddr=84:8f:69:f9:50:10
serverip=192.168.1.107
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
ubootfile=u-boot.ldr
update=tftp $(loadaddr) $(ubootfile);sf probe 1;sf erase 0 0x40000;sf write $(loadaddr) 0 $(filesize)

Environment size: 1309/8188 bytes
bfin>
```

filesize=a0e0ca = 10543306, which exactly the same size as the image i have in the laptop.

Note also that i succeded to download an image yesterday.

Is there something to configure in uBoot like start address or sthing like that, or i can say that flash is corrupted

I use:

BF609 board

blackfin-buildroot-2013R1-RC2

tftp server

Comment: Is it possible that the image is too large to fit in memory? It's possible that U-Boot's tftp just stops loading it without error, but then the CRC check when loading will obviously fail.

Comment: @Amout, Thanks for your feedback, 1-the memory fits the image, 2- what kind of problem lets tftp stops loading the image in your opinion ?

Comment: tftp has some stupid limit on image size, but that limit is more than 10MB IIRC. Anyway, if it would be truncated, then filesize would be smaller. Let me get this straight though: you have a working and a non-working image? Do both have the same load address? Not that that should matter because the CRC is checked before extracting to the load address...

Comment: @Arnout  *"... but that limit is more than 10MB IIRC."* -- If there is a TFTP limit, then the OP is not close to it.  I've been using U-Boot to download 60+ MB images (kernel+initramfs) without issues.

Comment: *"Note also that i succeded to download an image yesterday."*  -- Does *"an image"* mean a *different* image?  Are you claiming that the circumstances are completely identical between yesterday (download okay) and today (download failed)?

Comment: Thank you all, i am using the same image, however the problem doesn't come from the size of the image it seems it's due to the bad physical support i'am using, i changed the cable and it works fine, i thought that there is a kind of acknowledge for the packets, so if there is limits in the physical support it should be picked from the begining. by the way @Amout i just don't undrestand how the load addresses can make issues